# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop and does not save in my json-server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, crud, json-server

I keep getting error *"Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop"* on console log. I think there is something wrong in the

> axios.delete('http://localhost:3000/contacts/${id}

' or

> axios.put('http://localhost:3000/contacts/${isUpdate.id}'

It works, but does not configure in the json-server that I made. So the changes does not happen in the json-server.

[image]

The "save" button works, and added new data into my json-server. But, when I tried to edit, or delete, it does not save the changed in json-server.

**My code:**

```
import "./App.css";
import List from "./List";
import { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import {uid} from "uid";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
    
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
    
    function handleChange(e) {
        let data = { ...formData };


     data[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        setFormData(data);
    }
    
const [isUpdate, setIsUpdate] = useState({ id: null, status: false});
    

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
     name: "",
     telp: "",
  });
    
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:3000/contacts").then((res) => {
           console.log(res.data);
            setContacts(res?.data ?? []);
        });
    }, []);
    
    
    
  function handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Oke Bos!");
    
      let data = [...contacts];
      
      if(formData.name === "") {
          return false;
      }
      
      if(formData.telp === "") {
          return false;
      }
      
      if ( isUpdate.status){
          data.forEach((contact) => {
              if (contact.id === isUpdate.id) {
                  contact.name = formData.name;
                  contact.telp = formData.telp;
              }
          });
                        
        axios.put('http://localhost:3000/contacts/${isUpdate.id}', {
                        name: formData.name,
                        telp: formData.telp,
                        })
                .then((res) => {
                alert("Berhasil edit data!");
                });
      } else {
            
            let newData = { id: uid(), name: formData.name, telp: formData.telp };
            data.push(newData);
            axios.post("http://localhost:3000/contacts", newData).then((res) => {
             alert("Data telah disimpan cok!");
            });
   
        }
    // tambah kontak yee
   
 
setIsUpdate({id: null, status: false});
setContacts(data);      
setFormData({ name: "", telp: ""});
    
}
    
    function handleEdit(id) {
        let data = [...contacts];
        let foundData = data.find((contact) => contact.id === id);
        setFormData({ name: foundData.name, telp: foundData.telp});
        setIsUpdate({id: id, status: true});
    }
    
    function handleDelete(id) {
        let data = [...contacts];
        let filteredData = data.filter((contact) => contact.id !== id);
        axios.delete('http://localhost:3000/contacts/${id}').then((res) => {
            alert("Data telah dihapus");
        });
        
        setContacts(filteredData);
        
    }
    
    
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className="px-3 py-3">My Contact List</h1>

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="px-3 py-4">
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="">Name</label>
          <input type="text" 
      className="form-control"
      onChange={handleChange}
      value={formData.name} 
      name="name" />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group mt-3">
          <label htmlFor="">No. Telp</label>
          <input type="text" 
      className="form-control" 
      onChange={handleChange}
      value={formData.telp} 
      name="telp" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary w-100 mt-3">
            Save
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>

      <List handleDelete={handleDelete} handleEdit={handleEdit} data={contacts} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### The list component:

```
import React from "react";

export default function List({data,handleEdit,handleDelete}) {
  return (
    <div className="list-group">
      {
        data.map((contact) => {
            return (
        <div className="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <div className="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
          <h5 className="mb-1">{contact.name}</h5>
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => handleEdit(contact.id)} className="btn btn-sm btn-link">Edit</button>
            <button onClick={() => handleDelete(contact.id)} className="btn btn-sm btn-link">Del</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p className="mb-1">{contact.telp}</p>
      </div>
            );
        })}
     
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

I follow the tutorial, the code is like this, i checked it in so many times. But still it does not configure well into json-server  like what i see on youtube.

Comment: Can you show the `List` component?

Comment: yaa i just give it in the code above

Comment: You didn't give a key to this div in `List`: `<div className="list-group-item list-group-item-action">`. [Read more about keys here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Comment: I already read there, but I still don't understand. This is my first time using react js, and i ma a beginner in programming language.

Comment: Like this: `<div key={yourKey} className="list-group-item list-group-item-action">`

Comment: I checked the code again on youtube, but he also does not add key in that div

Comment: I don't know what key is this to put there

Comment: You can pass the contact ID or the index as a key. But I don't recommend passing index

Comment: I added become like this:<div key={contact.id} className="list-group-item list-group-item-action"> it does not showing error again, but the changed still does not happen in json-server

Comment: Every contact should have a unique ID

Comment: It is has a uniqe id, I use uid for making it uniqe in every contact

Comment: Now when i click delete button, it gives me this error in the pict: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b-WN_kpvs7128dKeKpjIXrqO4UVryhsd/view?usp=sharing 

The data is deleted, but still does not configure to json-server